# Как при отправке сообщения с url адресом сайта, сделать вложение

Tags: python, discord

И так, у меня есть сайт https://discordwebutillity.herokuapp.com/ я хочу чтобы когда я его присылал в каком-то чате в дискорде, то отсылался "ембед", например вот гитхаб[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать также но чтобы это было при отправки url сайта? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если что делал сайт на python flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать Open Graph, а именно добавить в свой шаблон в теги meta метаданные.
Основные метаданные:

1. og:title  - заголовок станицы
2. og:description - краткое описание
3. og:url - ссылка на страницу
4. og:image - ссылка на изображение.

Наиболее полная информация - [Протокол Open Graph](https://ruogp.me/)

Вот конкретно ваш пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Минимальный пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>

  <meta property="og:url" content="https://hottabxp.github.io"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Имя сайта" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Описание" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Заголовок" />
  <meta property="og:image" 
 content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот как это выглядит в телеграм:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавить в html тег <html lang="en" prefix="og: //ogp.me/ns#"> и в head тег добавить <meta property="og:title" content="Discord Web Utils " />
    <meta property="og:description" content="dsc" /> и тд. да? @SergeyKarbivbichiy

Comment: @ГугОль Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое! работает